# Change character with special format into a Date

Tags: r

How do I change a character looking like `"01.01.2016  16:33:03"` into a date? I already tried:

```
data$Date <- as.Date(data$Date, origin = "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S")
```

but just get an error message that `character string is not in a standard unambiguous format`

Comment: Change `origin` to `format`. But that will just give you the date part. If you want time also, use `as.POSIXct` instead of `as.Date`.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
this = "01.01.2016 16:33:03"
as.POSIXct(this, format = "%m.%d.%Y %H:%M:%S")
```

Definitely check out `?POSIXct` for the full documentation. The main point that might be confusing to you is that you need to define `format` to be the format that the string is currently and NOT what you want it to be.

While you're at it, also take a look at `?as.Date` and the `zoo` package which has a few neat functions like `as.yearmon()`.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is the `lubridate` package.

```
library(lubridate)
x <- '01.01.2016  16:33:03'
y <- mdy_hms(x)
```

Then you can use `month(y)`,`day(y)` etc. to access specific parts of the date.